# kernel update for 16.04 bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I seem to not often be able to get my headphones to connect on my laptop. I am using a thinkpad x220 and all system updates are installed. Using blue man once they are connected to change the audio profile. It seems I just can't turn already paired headphones on and have them auto-connect. Usually have to just pair again every time, which doesn't always work either. Is there a way to connect them through the command line. Also, is there a kernel update or anything else that is a known fix for bluetooth at this time? Thanks!

Comment: You have a specific problem with some hardware and user space settings. The problem is not clear to me. There is no generic "bluetooth problem" that can be fixed.

Comment: From my knowledge so far, it's not hardware as my headphones work perfectly fine on my iphone and other laptop running 14.04 - same settings as well. I am having trouble with connecting my headphones with 16.04.

Comment: I do not have trouble with connecting MY headphones on 16.04. So... The problem may be specific to your laptop hardware or BIOS, etc.

Comment: I thought this was a forum for help - Some things work on others computers and sometimes they don't work on others due to settings or a software update needed re-configured. I stated my problem with what I've tried and asked for a recommendation.

Comment: This is NOT a forum, nor it is a help center. If you describe your specific problem more precisely and write a good QUESTION, there is a chance that someone will write a good ANSWER to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thus I did. I asked if there was a kernel update that proposed blue tooth fixes known to users testing them out. I also asked if there is a manual way to connect them using the headphones BD address.

Comment: In particular, this is what I can't get to turn on, even with unpairing, turning off and on, restarting bluetooth services, etc... http://imgur.com/a/khhNO